# Is there a similar Express.js "trust proxy" configuration in NGINX?

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, proxy

We have a HAProxy serving as a load balancer with SSL configured, it's in front of a NGINX serving static files. Apparently NGINX is not inheriting information from `X-Forwarded` headers set from the upstream HAProxy.

For example:

`curl https://[domain]/folder` -> `HAProxy [ssl]` -> `NGINX [non-ssl]`, where /folder is serving an `index.html` file.

NGINX then performs a `301` redirect to `http://[domain]/folder/` and instead it should perform a redirect to `https://[domain]/folder/`.

In Express.js the `trust proxy` configuration indicates the app is behind a front-facing proxy, and to use the `X-Forwarded-*` headers to determine original protocol information.

Is there any similar `trust proxy` configuration in NGINX?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that NGINX redirects any request to a folder without a trailing slash. This can be avoided by using `try_files` instead of `index` module.

Instead of `index index.html index.htm;` it fixed by using `try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/index.htm;`.